# Solve Laravel InvalidArgumentException: Authentication views not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-permission

I updated laravel 5.6 project to laravel 6 in order to use the laravel-permission spatie package. It uses the default auth provided by Laravel. I can't access the auth routes and it appears as I am logged in while still seeing Login | Register on the navbar.
This is my route list

```
         | GET|HEAD | /                      |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user               |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                   | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST     | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | password/reset         | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | {any}                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\LexaController@index                              | web          |
```

Comment: The route is fine, it's the view it can't find. Check the functions `RegisterController@showRegistrationForm` and  `LoginController@showLoginForm`, and make sure the views there exist inside of your resources folder.

Comment: Hi @aynber thank you for the suggestion. I have gone to the login controller and when I try to go to ```use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;``` it cannot reference it. That seems to be the problem. What can I do?

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue, since the error is mentioning the view, not the use statement. That is most likely just an IDE issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error suggests that Laravel can't find your auth views. Is your register and login view located at: `resources/views/auth`? You might have to move them there if they aren't.

Comment: Yes those files are present in the resources/views/auth folder.